# Тире, требующее обоснования

Tags: тире

Можно ли это тире, стоящее перед вопросом, тем оправдать, что здесь можно, например, *поэтому* подставить? Или можно только точку перед этом вопросом поставить, а потом — сам вопрос?

> Мне бы хотелось с нею поговорить кой о чём, например после 3-го урока, — можешь ей сказать, чтобы на 3-й этаж подошла она?

Comment: Вы не знаете, что такое  синтаксическая синонимия? Одно и то же содержание текста можно записать различными способами. Здесь нет таких понятий, что одним способом можно, а другим нельзя.  Выбирайте подходящий вариант в пределах грамматики.